# How is a message $\mu$ encrypted in a witness encryption scheme below? What does C(x) = 1 mean below?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

I was reading [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/431.pdf) paper, where I came across the following statement on Pg 4 under the **Homomorphic Commitments**:

> A witness encryption scheme, associated with a
> NP language, consists of an encryption and a decryption algorithm: Anyone can encrypt their message **µ**
> under an NP instance and the decryption algorithm can obtain **µ** using the witness to this instance. We
> use witness encryption as follows: The sender encrypts **µ** under the instance **A** · R<sub>**C, x**</sub> + **C(x)** G which is
> obtained by homomorphically evaluating upon the commitments using the circuit **C**. The authority releases
> the decomitment R<sub>**C,x**</sub> as witness which would then allow anyone to recover **µ** if and only if **C(x) = 1**.

where **A** is a uniformly sampled matrix from **Z**<sub>q</sub><sup>**m x n**</sup>.

In the above statement, where is the message encryption done? Does it have anything to do with the matrix **G** in the statement ? What does **C(x) = 1** actually mean in this statement? If its the output of the Circuit **C** on the committed value **( x )** which should be 1, why should that always be the case ?

Please Help.

Comment: I think if C(x) = 0, then perhaps the trapdoor computation which is explained later in the paper won't be possible, and hence would prevent public decryption. Any add ons to this conclusion would be helpful.